# Add a custom participant listing option

Tags: civievent

I need a participant list option (Name + employer) in CiviEvent. I've created an participant list option. But I guess I've to build my own template. I guess it is documented somewhere but I could manage to find it. Could someone help me finding my way?

Comment: Could you please give us more information?  Do you need this list to be public-facing, or do you just need to generate a report?  What CMS are you using, and what version of CiviCRM?

Answer (score 1):

I would add a custom group to Participant, that should show in CiviCRM automatically whenever you do something with a participant.

Comment: It would be helpful for others if you could elaborate a bit more.

Comment: My assumption from the question is that additional data needs to be kept for a participant, Name and employer. You can create addition custom data in CiviCRM from Administer/Customize Data and Screens/Custom Fields. Here you can add a group of fields to entities, one of the entities is Participant. If you add the desired fields here they will show in the CiviCRM UI whenever a participant is displayed.